# PHP Combine Date and Time fields to form DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, google-calendar-api

I have 3 separate fields:

```
// date object in the format yyyy-mm-dd
$service_1_date 

// time object in the format 00:00:00
$booking->service_1_time_start

// time object in the format 00:00:00
$booking->service_1_time_end
```

I have set these up as separate fields because I manipulate them separately in my application.

However as I am creating a Google Calendar event I must pass a datetime object as one value like this:

```
Event::create([
           'name' => 'New Booking',
           'startDateTime' => '',
           'endDateTime' => '',
        ]);
```

In order for me to pass the `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` parameters I must first combine my date and time objects. So my question is how do I combine my date and time objects to make it into one datetime object?

> it is expecting an instance of Carbon

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:

```
 $newDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$service_1_date $booking->service_1_time_start"));
```